# can we find actual function from $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Given  $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ such that $f(8)=15$  and $f(12)=24$ can we find explicitly $f(x)$

From $$f(8)=f(4)+f(2)$$ and $$f(4)=2f(2)$$

So $$f(2)=5$$

Now the functional equation is actually satisfied by $$f(x)=\log_{a} x$$ If we choose base $a$ as fifth root of $2$ we have $$f(x)=\log_{2^{.2}} x$$ 
But with this $f(x)$  it wont satisfy $f(12)=24$ So can we find $f(x)$ explicitly

Comment: You should also specify the set of admissible values for $x,y$. For example,  if all real numbers ar admissible, then $f(t)=0$ for all $t$ ... ! (take $y=0$).

Comment: Without additional assumptions about $f$, this determines only $f(x)$ for $x=\pm 2^n3^m$. Also, we see that $f(0)$ cannot be defined. -- Indeed, you can pick arbitrary values $f(p)$ for all primes and obtain a unique solution defined on $\Bbb Q^\times$.

Answer (score 1):

Your current rules very much underdetermine the function. Infinitely many functions satisfy what you have listed so far. You need to add more to specify a particular function. So **no, you cannot find $f(x)$**. Examples of how to construct multiple functions satisfying this are in the comments.